# Java code run in eclipse but dont find the mysql driver when running in terminal

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, terminal

I'm trying to run a program in java that use mysql connector java to JDBC, the program run in Eclipse but in terminal I get that error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at application.Program.main(Program.java:11)
```

I am using maven to manage the dependecys but it dont solved my problem

My SO is an archlinux, if its relevant

Comment: How are you running the command on the terminal? It looks like maybe the dependencies aren’t included on the classpath.

Comment: Check that MySQL dependency doesn't have `scope`/`optional` configured. Are you using mvn command to run the application?

Comment: Did your jar include all the dependencies ? Seems its not. There should be enough resources and tutorials in internet to resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

Add mysql-connector jar in classPath or add it in the environment as in environment variable